# How to re-enable drivers on not bootable Windows 10?

Tags: windows, drivers, bsod, autorun

I have used Sysinternals Autoruns and disabled some intel drivers from autorun (similar to msconfig), after which my Windows 10 instance won't boot (blue screen) and Win 10 Install USB can't autofix the issue.

The question is, how to enable these drivers back through WinPE shell?

Comment: Try starting from a Windows 10 ISO and do a startup Repair.  See if that re-enables drivers.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you have any data or installations worth keeping, **make a full drive image** so that you can recover from a failed attempt to repair. There are many tools to use, such as [Macrium Rescue Environment](https://www.macrium.com/blog/the-macrium-rescue-environment-cca57a4ebc61).

The way Autoruns disables *some* items is by moving the Registry entry for the item to key, *AutorunsDisabled*.

[image: AutorunsDisabled]

1. **If** you can [start Windows in Safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234), then you could try using Autoruns to enable the drivers, or try editing the Registry directly, moving the drivers up one level from the *Autoruns Disabled* subkey.
2. Win PE (or Win RE) *by itself* does not have the utilities such as Autoruns or Regedit to fix the issue. However, there are bottable Windows (and Linux) files such has [Hirens Boot CD](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) that have already slipstreamed various repair tools, so you **can** try using the included Autoruns or try [editing the Registry](https://knowitnow.quora.com/Edit-windows-registry-without-booting-offline-Registry-Editor-PE-Video) directly. *N.B.* Editing the Registry when not logged in has some limitations and is more prone to disastrous failure.
3. If all else fails, perform a **full** Windows 10 install, effectively wiping the drive, and then restore what you can from the full drive image.
4. Consider installing another OS than Windows 10, whether Windows 11 or an alternative, such as [Ubuntu Linux](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started). [EOL for Windows10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-10-home-and-pro) is in less than one year, at this time. You can test many Linux distros by running from a bootable USB, without need to install -- only put it on SSD or HDD if it serves your purposes.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the answer. I have a ton of VST plugins with activations, including legacy ones on that system, so I really wouldn't like to reinstall all that. But yes, better move to Win 11 soon.

Comment: @Some_Dud, you might want to take a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/AudioHandbook/UsingVSTPlugins . Yes, there would be pain in the move. OTOH, *if* the PC is used *only* for MIDI, and not connected to a network, then security updates are less urgent, so you might stick with Win10.